# Правильный вариант подключения шрифта на сайт?

Tags: html, шрифты, frontend

Подключил шрифт HelveticaNeueCyr-Light через @font-face в формате otf и ttf.
В ubuntu (chrome), Mac(chrome) всё ок, но на Windows (Chrome) шрифт "прыгает" буквы одна выше другой.
В чем проблема? И какой правильный вариант подключения шрифтов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я обычно использую такое подключение шрифтов, в форматах .eot,.woff,.svg и .ttf, и никаких проблем с кроссбраузерностью никогда не возникало, если нет шрифта во всех нужных форматах, можно конвертировать на [сайте](https://onlinefontconverter.com/) Пример для шрифта Futura:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: "FuturaMedium";
      src: url("../fonts/Futura/FuturaPT-Medium.eot");
      src: url("../fonts/Futura/FuturaPT-Medium.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype');
      src: local('@'), url("../fonts/Futura/FuturaPT-Medium.woff") format('woff'),
      url("../fonts/Futura/FuturaPT-Medium.svg") format('svg'),
      url("../fonts/Futura/FuturaPT-Medium.ttf") format('trutype');
     }
```